# Automatic brace completion not working in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, productivity-power-tools

I installed the [Productivity Power Tools 2012 extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) and while some of the features in the extension work, such as middle click scroll, automatic brace completion is not working.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether have You Automatic Brace Completion option turn on ?
(in Tools -> Options -> Productivity Power Tools node)

Comment: Yes, all of the options are turned on.

Comment: Hmmmmm...maybe You're tring to use PPT with other language than C# or VB. This function works only for this languages.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I'm using C++. As far as I can tell, the Productivity Power Tools page doesn't say anything about only supporting C# or VB. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension from Microsoft called [Brace Completer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e33cb22-d4ac-4f5a-902f-aff5177cc94d) and it works for c++, CSS, jscript, C#.